# Passing Props to New Component - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, api, browser, router

Wondering if I could get some help.  I'm building a job board and I'm using github jobs as my jobs API feed.  Here's a codesandbox link to my project so far:

https://codesandbox.io/s/34kzz5k6k1
(You need CORS chrome plugin to make the api work).

Basically:

1. In my index.js file, I'll calling the API in my 'ComponentDidMount'.
2. And by default, jobs appear for 'New York, on my page.
3. When you search for 'developer' jobs in 'london', in my 'HandleSubmit', you can see I'm pushing the results to a new URL '/jobresults'.
4. I'm using browser router to do this.

The problem I'm having though.  So my default jobs are still appearing on /jobresults.  As well as my 'London' search results, which appear underneath.

How do I only make 'london' jobs appear on this page?

I thought I could try and build a job board all front end.  But now I'm think I need REST routing on the backend as well?

Maybe saving my API call in a database.  And then displaying the results on a 'show' route?

Any guidance you can give, would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: you can pass values with routes - check docs - show defaults when no params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here that really needs to be revised. The way you've structured the app is anti-pattern (non-stardard/bad practice) and will cause you more headaches as the application becomes more dynamic.

I've gone ahead and restructured the entire app. I encourage you to deconstruct it and follow the application flow, and then take your project and fix it accordingly.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v873j0600y (still requires CORS extension)

---

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import JobForm from "./components/JobForm";
import JobResults from "./components/JobResults";
import NavHeader from "./components/NavHeader";
import "uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => (
  <main>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <section>
        <NavHeader />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={JobForm} />
          <Route path="/jobs" component={JobResults} />
          <Route path="/jobresults/:id" component={JobResults} />
        </Switch>
      </section>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </main>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**NavHeader.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default () => (
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
        <li style={{ display: "inline", marginRight: 20 }}>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li style={{ display: "inline", marginRight: 20 }}>
          <Link to="/jobs">Jobs</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
);
```

**JobForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class JobForm extends Component {
  state = { searchData: "", cityData: ""};

  // HANDCHANGE FOR JOB SEARCH
  handleChange = e => this.setState({ searchData: e.target.value });

  // HANDLE CHANGE FOR LOCATION SEARCH
  handleChangeLocation = e => this.setState({ cityData: e.target.value });

  // HANDLE SUBMIT
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { cityData, searchData } = this.state;
    if (!cityData || !searchData) return;
    this.props.history.push(
      `/jobresults/positions?description=${searchData}&location=${cityData}`
    );
  };

  render = () => (
    <section className="hero homepage">
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="title has-text-white">USA Creative City</h1>
        <h2 className="title has-text-white">Start your job search here!</h2>
        <form className="level-item" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="inputstyle field has-addons">
            <div className="control ">
              <input
                className="uk-input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Software Engineer..."
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                style={{ width: 200 }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="control ">
              <input
                className="uk-input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="City"
                onChange={this.handleChangeLocation}
                style={{ width: 200 }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="control">
              <button
                style={{ width: 200 }}
                className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
              >
                <i
                  style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
                  className="fas fa-search"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />Search Jobs
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

**JobResults.js**

```
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import qs from "qs";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import ShowResults from "./ShowResults";
import NoResults from "./NoResults";

const getRandomInt = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
const locations = ["Los Angeles", "New York", "San Mateo", "San Francisco"];
const descriptions = ["Developer", "Engineer", "MySQL", "MongoDB"];

export default class JobResults extends Component {
  state = { isLoading: true, jobs: [], error: "" };

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true }, () => this.fetchData());
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = () => this.fetchData();

  fetchData = () => {
    let { description, location } = qs.parse(this.props.location.search, {
      ignoreQueryPrefix: true
    });

    if (!description || !location) {
      description = descriptions[getRandomInt(3)];
      location = locations[getRandomInt(3)];
    }

    axios(`https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=${description}&location=${location}`)
      .then(({ data }) => this.setState({ isLoading: false, jobs: data.slice(0, 9) }))
      .catch(err => this.setState({ isLoading: false, err: err.toString() }));
  };

  render = () =>
    this.state.isLoading 
     ? <Spinner />
     : <section>
        <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }} className="has-text-centered animated shake slow">
          RESULTS
        </h3>
        <div className="columns is-multiline">
          {isEmpty(this.state.jobs) 
            ? <NoResults err={this.state.err} />
            : <ShowResults jobs={this.state.jobs} />
          }
        </div>
      </section>
    );
}
```

**ShowResults.js**

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React from "react";

export default ({ jobs }) => (
  map(jobs, ({ id, created_at, company_logo, title, company, location, url }) => (
      <div className="result" key={id}>
        <img className="image" src={company_logo} />
        <h4 className="has-text-left purple">Location: {title}</h4>
        <h5 className="has-text-left purple">
          Created on: {created_at}
        </h5>
        <h5 className="has-text-left purple">Company: {company}</h5>
        <h5 className="has-text-left purple">Location: {location}</h5>
        <a className="uk-button uk-button-primary" href={url} target="_new">
          apply on github
        </a>
        <a
          className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
          style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          href={url}
          target="_new"
        >
          apply on creative jobs
        </a>
      </div>
    )
);
```

**NoResults.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ err }) => (
  err 
    ? <p style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "red" }}>
        <i style={{ marginRight: 5 }} className="fas fa-exclamation-circle" /> 
        {err}
      </p>
    : <p style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "grey" }}>
        <i style={{ fontSize: 22, marginRight: 5 }} className="far fa-calendar-times"/>
        No jobs matching that criteria.
      </p>
);
```

**Spinner.js**

```
import React from "react";

const spinners = () => {
  let children = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    children.push(<div key={i} className={`sk-circle${i} sk-circle`} />);
  }
  return children;
};

export default () => <div className="sk-fading-circle">{spinners()}</div>;
```

Comment: Hi @matt-carlotta, thank you for your post and message, I really appreciate it!  I'm a newbie in react though, (5 months + 1 project).  So as much as I appreciate the changes you've made, I don't understand a lot of what you've done and why.  You've reengineered the complete app...
1) why is this approach better?
2) what is "import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty"?
3) what is "import qs from "qs"?
4) Can you break down exactly what is happening in JobResults.js.  The JS syntax seems advanced.

Comment: I apprecaite the work you've done to help me, but you've changed/added so much, if you could add comments for every change you've made in the CodeSandbox link, that would be really helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm going to go ahead and try and research/break everything down myself.  Thank you!

Comment: Also why have you added "default" in class component?

Comment: HI @matt-calotta, I've added in questions as comments in your codesandbox link.  Please could you answer them, (as comments too in the code)?  thanks!

Comment: I don't see any comments, and it looks like you have forked the sandbox. You'll have to post the new fork's URL for me to see them. In the meantime: 1.) Flexible so that you can add more routes/components and not be tidied down to strictly `JobResults`. 2.) Lodash isEmpty makes it easier to see if an obj/arr is empty since `!this.state.jobs` always returns true (because it exists regardless of length). 3.) The module `qs` parses `this.props.location.search` from the URL, for example: `?description=Developer&location=San Jose` breaks down to `description=Developer` and `location=San Jose`.

Comment: 4.) Too hard to explain when you're limited to 600 characters! When I get some time, I'll add comments to my sandbox.

Comment: And to answer your other question: `export default class Example extends Component` is shorter syntax for `class Example extends Component`, `export default Example`. Same thing. `default` means when you `import Example from './Example` you, by default, are importing that class/function. When do you `export const Example  () => {}` then you need to `import { Example } from './Example`, however if you leave the function nameless and add default: `export default () => {}` now becomes `import Example from './Example`.

Comment: Hi @matt-carlotta - thank you so much for taking the time out for answering these questions.  And you're right! i didn't share the correct link. :)
https://codesandbox.io/s/32xl2o69j1
  If you're able to spare some time over the next day or so, to check out my comments, that would be really really awesome.  I appreciate the refactor.  it's the only way to learn!  Thank you. Reena :)

Comment: @Reena Verma  - Updated https://codesandbox.io/s/v873j0600y with comments. Please read them in the following order: 1. `JobForm.js`, 2. `JobResults.js`, 3. `NoResult.js`, 4. `ShowResults.js`. Also, please read the React documentation on lifecycle methods: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: Hey @matt-carlotta !  Thank you for doing this! Very much appreciated and really, really super helpful for sure.  I'm just half way through taking everything in, (work has been manic today), but I'll finish this off tomorrow for sure.  I think what I'll end up doing, is rebuilding the app, using your method - just so I really understand everything to the detail.  But thank you for the detail you added to the comments - so far they make sense and I'm very grateful indeed. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. As a challenge, I suggest you try doing what you had intended. Display some jobs on initial load (under the form). Then update the jobs JSON when a form has been submitted. This way, it'll challenge you to work with arrays/objects, unique ids, and react life cycle methods. All of it, under one route.

Comment: Thank you Matt.  Absolutely.  I was scared when i saw the initial changes haha.  But this is a great way to learn.  I'm in a cafe now and can't wait to break this all down. And rebuild.  Your suggestion is also a good one.  I'll try and make it work with my current setup too, knowing what the ideal solution is.  Thank you very much.  Best help i've had on this site so far!!! :)

Comment: You bet, any time. In the meantime, here's one way of doing the challenge (DO NOT LOOK AT IT UNTIL AFTER YOU'VE COMPLETED YOURS): https://codesandbox.io/s/jpjrw27zo5

Comment: hey hey hey, I've had a horrendus few weeks, where I've just had to decline an awesome junior dev role.  Just picking this up again now and thank you for the second solution!! i have a long train journey ahead of my this friday, so let me read and come back to you then.  Thank you :)